# mensaje warning NaNs en gammamixEM()

Tags: r

Estoy utilizando la función gammamixEM() de mixtools en R, y al finalizar el cálculo obtengo los parámetros pero me aparece este aviso.

```
x <- c(34.290, 34.798, 34.798, 185.420, 28.448, 29.718, 32.766, 21.844, 36.576)

g <-gammamixEM(x)
g

Warning messages:
1: In dgamma(x, shape = alpha[j], scale = beta[j]) : NaNs produced
2: In dgamma(x, shape = alpha[j], scale = beta[j]) : NaNs produced
```

Tengo que volver a correr la función hasta que ya no aparezca el aviso. ¿A que se debe específicamente?, y ¿cómo puedo hacer para que ya no arroje este aviso corriendo la función una sola vez?.

Saludos y desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar la llamada a `gammamixEM()`?

Comment: Hola, Patricio. He editado mi pregunta y he agregado lo que me indicas. Saludos y muchas gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada un `warning` es simplemente eso, una advertencia, podría ser un problema o no, e ignorarse. Si en este caso estamos ante  un problema, no puedo decirlo por que mis conocimientos de estadística son bien limitados, aunque estoy inclinado a pensar que estas advertencias bien podrían ignorarse.

¿Dónde esta el problema? tal como dice el error, en alguna de las varias veces que llama a la función base [`dgamma()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html) se le pasa parámetro `shape` con un valor menor a 0. Lo cual está esta claramente documentado y no permitido. El ejemplo del problema sería algo así:

```
> dgamma(c(1,2,3), shape = -1)
[1] NaN NaN NaN
Warning message:
In dgamma(c(1, 2, 3), shape = -1) : NaNs produced
```

Aún sin saber lo que hace `gammamixEM()`, te decía que estaba inclinado a pensar que podemos obviar estos `warnings`, básicamente por que se trata de una rutina no "determinística", es decir que tiende a darte resultados distintos de acuerdo al momento en que la ejecutes, esto es por que en algún momento de la función se hace un `runif()`, por lo que el resultado final no depende plenamente del vector de entrada ni de ningún parámetro, por lo que en algún momento se generarán las condiciones para que se produzca este `warning` (de hecho, no sé si te has dado cuenta pero en algún momento puede que hasta recibas un mensaje de error, no un error), esto me hace pensar que se trata simplemente de una condición no del todo bien controlada por la función.

Algunos ejemplos:

```
library(mixtools)

x <- c(34.290, 34.798, 34.798, 185.420, 28.448, 29.718, 32.766, 21.844, 36.576)

# Con esta semilla aleatoria, la ejecución funcionará perfectamente
set.seed(1)
g <- gammamixEM(x)
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
number of iterations= 14 

# Con esta otra semilla, y con los mismos datos obtendremos los warnings
set.seed(11)
g <- gammamixEM(x)
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
Note: Choosing new starting values. 
number of iterations= 16 
Warning messages:
1: In dgamma(x, shape = alpha[j], scale = beta[j]) : NaNs produced
2: In dgamma(x, shape = alpha[j], scale = beta[j]) : NaNs produced
```

Si eventualmente necesitarás ocultar esos `warnings` podrías intentar hacer uso de [`suppressWarnings()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warning.html) de esta forma:

```
set.seed(11)
g <- suppressWarnings(gammamixEM(x))
```

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Esta muy clara tu respuesta. Saludos.